# How can we derive x_0 bsed on epsilon and x_t in Denoising Diffusion Probabilistic Models (DDPM) paper?

Tags: neural-networks, langevin-diffusion

In Equation. 15 of the [DDPM paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.11239.pdf) it derives $x_o$ directly based on $\epsilon$ and $x_t$.
[image]

I understand the iterative denoising that achieves $x_{t-1}\leftarrow x_{x}$:
$$
x_{t - 1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\bar{\alpha}_t}}\big(x_t - \frac{\beta_t}{\sqrt{1-\bar{\alpha}_t}}\epsilon_{\theta}(x_t)\big) + \beta_t\mathbf{I}\cdot \mathbf{z}.
$$

But how can we marginalize all the steps and directly achieve $x_0$? I tried to derive Equation 15 by myself but couldn't get that result.